# Python logging writing to multiple separate log files

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web application that runs a bunch of helper scripts. Each of these scripts writes its own log. I am noticing that the scripts are writing to each others logs. These scripts are launched by separate users/sessions. Whats going on?

Here is the implementation of the logger within ScriptA

```
import logging
   logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filename='/var/logs/scriptA.log',level=logging.DEBUG)  

  logging.info("INFO: test log from scriptA"))
```

same for scriptB but say someone runs scriptB, it writes to scriptA.log instead of scriptB.log

it seems logging is created a shared global module. How can I stop this

EDIT: most solutions here are for 2 separate logs within the same class. my issue is separate scripts/classes writing to each others logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the logging module for Python is a global module. I ran to the same issue before. I used this code to separate the logs for each module/class.

```
import logging
import sys

class SampleCass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_logger()
        self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @run_one
    def set_logger():
        # this separates the logging from different modules
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s ' +
                                      '%(name)s]: %(message)s',
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handler to the class logger
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)

def run_once(func):
    """
    A decorator to run function only once
    :type func: __builtin__.function
    :return:
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        if not wrapper.has_run:
            wrapper.has_run = True
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.has_run = False
    return wrapper
```

Now you can use self.log for your class and it will not interfere with the logging of other modules. run_one function ensures that when you import the function, it will only run once and only once. Hope it helps you.